# Perl `chop` removes two characters instead of one

Tags: perl

I'm using the command line to pass a string to a Perl program. For instance, this passes `"stackOveflow"` to the program `hello`

```
hello "stackOveflow"
```

I use [`chop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) to remove the last character from the last element of `@ARGV`

```
chop($ARGV[$#ARGV]);
```

and then print it

```
say "$ARGV[$#ARGV]";
```

I'm expecting `"stackOveflow` in the output, but instead I'm seeing `stackOveflo`

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: `perl -E 'say,chop,say for pop' "stackOveflow"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hello "stackOveflow"` tells the shell to execute the program `hello` and pass the string `stackOveflow` to it as an argument (similar to how `my $s = "stackOveflow";` assigns the string `stackOveflow` to `$x` in Perl).

[`chop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) removes the last character of the string, so the value changes from `stackOveflow` to `stackOveflo`.

```
$ perl -E'say $ARGV[-1]; chop($ARGV[-1]); say $ARGV[-1]' "stackOveflow"
stackOveflow
stackOveflo
```

Comment: Why is he getting the opening double-quote in the parm value?

Comment: the `""` are not intended as characters?

Comment: @Jonathan M, He's not.

Comment: @Yokupoku Maioku, Added to my answer.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku, are you *sure* you're getting `"stackOverflo` with a double-quote at the beginning?

Comment: @JonathanM excuse me i said something wrong , in otuput i'm not getting double quote at beginning, i'll update the question

Comment: @JonathanM see my last comment.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku, ok. That make a ton of difference.

Comment: +1 This has ended up being a nice answer. I suggest that you should explain the idea of *delimiters*, and that this is only one of the things that the (Bourne) shell does to your parameters.

Comment: @Borodin i was expecting your useful and complete answer/advices yesterday,but i think you was away...